# Session lost on htaccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, session, cakephp, mod-rewrite, cakephp-3.0

Juste found out that each time my url is rewritten through .htaccess CakePhp is initializing a new session for my user.

Here is my htaccess content :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Campagne(.+)Virale/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  Campagne\ Virale/$1   [L,NE]
</IfModule>
```

My session settings are as follow :

```
'Session' => [
    'defaults' => 'cake',
    'timeout' => 6000,
    'ini' => [
        'session.cookie_secure' => false
    ]
],
```

So when accessing https://exemple.com/ a new session is created while https://exemple.com/Campagne%20Virale/ works just fine.

Any idea why?  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem, as I understand it, was that Cakephp base cookie path is the same as the base path.  So the original and rewritten base paths seems to differ leading to a new session being generated.

To fix this issue, I specified the base cookie path in my app.php

```
'Session' => [
    'defaults' => 'cake',
    'ini' => [
        'session.cookie_path' => '/',
        'session.cookie_domain' => 'exemple.com'
    ]
],
```

If you've got a better explanation for this problem, feel free to answer for posterity's sake.